# Can Java be considered a managed programming language?

Tags: java

I am curious; can Java be referred to as a managed language? I am mainly thinking about the Microsoft model when it comes to unmanaged versus managed code (say native vc++ to C#). With the similarities between C# and Java as high-level languages, is it correct to call Java a managed language as well?

Comment: Please define "managed language". It's impossible to answer this question without a *precise* definition of what a "managed language" is.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. Java is considered a managed programming language as it's sandboxed well by the JVM. But the term "managed code" is microsoft specific.

Comment: I would flip this answer.  (1) "Managed code" is Windows-Only and (2) Java runs elsewhere than Windows.  I'm not sure that the JVM's running under windows actually use Windows official Managed Code.

Comment: @S.Lott Mono also uses this terminology on non-Windows platforms. So no, not “Windows-Only”.

Comment: @Konrad:  That's still on the CLI, not a JVM.  It isn't Windows-specific, but it's still a reasonable question.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph.  Good Point.  I stand corrected.  But does the JVM adhere to the managed code API's?  Or is the JVM merely similar to managed code?

Comment: @S.Lott I think Microsoft uses “managed code” more as an umbrella term rather than tying it to a specific implementation (IL, CLR). I may be mistaken though. “Managed” for me simply implies that execution of the code is “safe” because it relies on checking of pointer accesses etc. By that definition, JVM execution would also be managed.

Comment: @Konrad: I agree -- "managed" is much more a marketing term than a technical one. I'd go a bit further though: programmers and programming projects are largely considered nearly unmanageable, and I think the real intent is to imply that if you use Microsoft's "managed" (code, or whatever) that both will become more manageable -- and, incidentally, the managers will become a more important part of projects as well. In short, Microsoft is marketing directly to the people who control the money instead of to programmers, and hoping they'll convince the managers to buy from Microsoft.

Comment: From that viewpoint, I'd say that yes, Java is similar. Both take the position that programmers are incompetent, untrustworthy, and need to be "controlled". Both also basically define "management" as being carried out by force -- rather than persuading somebody to do things well, they assume that what's being managed will do as much wrong as possible, so the "manager" must ensure against everything they've defined as "wrong". In short, both are intended to appeal to the basest instincts of the worst managers.

Comment: Neither Java nor .Net assume incompetence on the part of developers, they just abstract away memory management. The term managed code comes form automatic memory management, i.e. garbage collection. It's not a marketing term (".Net" is the marketing term).

Answer (score 9):

Yes. A managed language is a language that runs in its own container.

Java is a managed language because you've got the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine) and in .NET you've got the [CLR](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime).

The term "managed code" seems to be something Microsoft specific, have a look at the [following](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code) wikipedia article.

Comment: I don’t think any definition of “managed” actually hinges on the presence of a garbage collector.

Comment: @Konrad: I've updated my answer.

Comment: The last paragraph of this answer seems to contradict the other two. The wikipedia article is pretty specific about "managed" relating to the CLR VM, not just any VM